# Adding Leaflet to wordpress website using Divi theme

Tags: wordpress, leaflet

I am trying to integrate leaflet map to my divi website. One of the plugins was there but that is not compatible with the theme. Is there any way i can integrate the leaflet using shortcode and it will be responsive on my site?

Comment: do you have the same problem is you try this plugin ? https://wordpress.org/plugins/osm/

Comment: I haven't tried this plugin but will it work the same as leaflet?

Comment: Did you try https://wordpress.org/plugins/leaflet-map/ ?

Answer (score 0):

The other way is you need to code it by yourself using the leafletjs open source code.
Just use the source code on this website: https://leafletjs.com/